# iOS, handle undetermined JSON data structure

Tags: ios, json

Its probably worth stating that i haven't yet found a good way to determine if a key has a value. I've tried comparing values to nil but that doesn't work. the only method i have found that works is determining if a value `isEqualToString:@""`. PHP's isset() is an ideal that i look for

---

I have JSON data coming in from an API. 
Typically the data is an array of objects like so:

```
data: {
 { 
   number = 50,
   position = left
 },
 {
  number = 40,
  position = right
 }
}
```

I can check values of this structure by using code such as:

```
[[self.data objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"number"]
```

Sometimes the data comes in as a single object:

```
data: {
  error = 1
}
```

I'm having difficulty handling this as when the single object data is parsed, `objectAtIndex:` causes the app to crash, naturally. 
How would i handle these two types of data structure?

Ive tried an IF OR,

```
if(![[self.data objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"error"] || [[self.data valueForKey:@"error"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
```

But the initial clause still causes the crash.

Comment: You should use objectForKey. valueForKey will not do what you think it does for some keys, and objectForKey is usually about five times faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically handle this situation like so:-

```
    if ([self.data isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)self.data;
        // do something with the array...
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"unexpected JSON data: %@", self.data);
    }
```

Comment: And you don't strictly need the cast to `jsonArray`, but I find it helps make the code more readable since it shows a semantic separation between the incoming JSON 'blob' and the validated array we are expecting.

Comment: This is a better way of solving my issue. I resolved it by editing at the API end, and converting the return into a single index'ed array so it would work with the same code as typical expected data does